# Helm re-install resources that already exist

Tags: kubernetes, resources, kubernetes-helm

How can I execute "helm install" command and re-install resources that I have defined in "templates"? I have some custom resources that already exist so I want to re-install them. It is possible to do that through a parameter in helm command?

Answer (score 7):

I think your main question is:

> I have some custom resources that already exist so I want to re-install them.

Which means **DELETE** then **CREATE** again.

### Short answer

No.. but it can be done thru workaround

### Detailed answer

Helm manages the RELEASE of the Kubernetes manifests by either:

- creating `helm install`
- updating `helm upgrade`
- deleting `helm delete`

However, you can recreate resources following one of these approaches :

**1. Twice Consecutive Upgrade**

If your chart is designed to enable/disable installation of resources with **Values** ( .e.g: `.Values.customResources.enabled`) you can do the following:

```sh
helm -n namespace upgrade <helm-release> <chart> --set customResources.enabled=false

# Then another Run
helm -n namespace upgrade <helm-release> <chart> --set customResources.enabled=true
```

So, if you are the builder of the chart, your task is to make the design functional.

**2. Using helmfile hooks**

[Helmfile](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile) is Helm of Helm.

It manage your helm releases within a single file called `helmfile.yaml`.

Not only that, but it also can call some **LOCAL commands** before/or/after installing/or/upgrading a Helm release.
This call which happen before or after, is named **hook**.

For your case, you will need **presync** hook.

If we organize your helm release as a Helmfile definition , it should be :

```yaml
releases:
- name: <helm-release>
  chart: <chart>
  namespace: <namespace>
  hooks:
  - events: ["presync"]
    showlogs: true
    command: kubectl
    args: [ "-n", "{{`{{ .Release.Namespace }}`}}", "delete", "crd", "my-custom-resources" ]
```

Now you just need to run `helmfile apply`

I know that CRD are not namespaced, but I put namespace in the hook just to demonstrate that Helmfile can give you the namespace of release as variable and no need to repeat your self.

Answer (score 6):

You can use rollback to current revision.
First find installed revision:

```bash
helm list -n <namespace>
```

Then you can run:

```bash
helm rollback <name> <revision_number> -n namespace
```

This will reinstall/restore what was installed latest. Be aware your revivion will get +1 revision.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `helm upgrade` to upgrade any existing deployed chart with changes.

The upgrade arguments must be a release and chart. The chart argument can be either: a chart reference(`example/mariadb`), a `path` to a chart directory, a packaged `chart`, or a fully qualified URL. For chart references, the latest version will be specified unless the `--version` flag is set.

To override values in a chart, use either the `--values` flag and pass in a file or use the `--set` flag and pass configuration from the command line, to force string values, use `--set-string`. In case a value is large and therefore you want not to use neither `--values` nor `--set`, use `--set-file` to read the single large value from file.

You can specify the `--values'/'-f` flag multiple times. The priority will be given to the last (right-most) file specified. For example, if both myvalues.yaml and override.yaml contained a key called 'Test', the value set in override.yaml would take precedence

For example

```
helm upgrade -f myvalues.yaml -f override.yaml redis ./redis
```

Comment: I have this error. I would reinstall this custom resource everytime helm install command is launched......helm upgrade --install --debug simulator-runtime .bob/simulator/simulator-1.0.0-h333cf6a.tgz --namespace=default --wait --timeout 900"

Error: release simulator-runtime failed: certificate.tls "simulator-certificate" already exists

Answer (score 0):

easier way I follow, especially for pre existing jobs during helm upgrade is do `kubectl delete job db-migrate-job --ignore-not-found`